# What is the English translation of Megillat Ta'anit 4:8

Tags: translation, yom-kippur

What is the English translation of Megillat Ta'anit 4:8? This text was referenced in a Jewish Publication Society book "Outside of Scripture"  [Jewish writings of the Second Temple Period] citing it as giving additional information about the Yom Kippur fast. The article is about the writing on special laws by Philo of Alexandria.

Comment: I think that you need to point more specificaly to what the book says about it so that we can identify where on the pages it is

Answer (score 1):

You appear to mean the **Mishnah** Ta'anis [chapter 4 misnah 8](http://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Taanit.4.8?lang=en&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all)

> R. Simeon ben Gamaliel says, "Never were more joyous festivals in
>   Israel than the fifteenth of Av and Yom Kippur, for on them the
>   maidens of Jerusalem used to go out dressed in white garments—borrowed
>   ones, in order not to cause shame to those who had them not of their
>   own;—these clothes were also to be previously immersed, and thus they
>   went out and danced in the vineyards, saying, Young men, look and
>   observe well whom you are about to choose [as a spouse]; regard not
>   beauty [alone], but rather look to a virtuous family, for
>   'Gracefulness is deceitful, and beauty is a vain thing, but the woman
>   that feareth the Lord, she is worthy of praise' (Prov. 31:3); and it
>   is also said (Prov. 31:31), 'Give her of the fruit of her hands, and
>   let her own works praise her in the gates.' And thus is it said [in
>   allusion to this custom], 'Go out, maidens of Jerusalem, and look on
>   King Solomon, and on the crown wherewith his mother has encircled [his
>   head] on the day of his espousals, and on the day of the gladness of
>   his heart' (Song of Songs 3:11); 'the day of his espousals,' alludes
>   to the day of the gift of the law, and 'the day of the gladness of his
>   heart,' was that when the building of the Temple was completed." May
>   it soon be rebuilt in our days. Amen!

Comment: The orginal citation was M. Ta'an 4:8.  The book I'm reading has a list of abbreviations, the closest to M. Ta'an that is listed is Meg.  Ta'an which is expanded to Megillat Ta'anit.  The publisher missed this M. Ta'an in compiling the abbreviations list.  The point of the essay is to show Philo of Alexandria's understanding of how Yom Kippur was observed.  The author of the essay says there was the Fast and prayers and supplication. M. Ta'an 8:4  show another activity of Yom Kippur was dancing maidens. The book is about Jewish writings outside of the Tanakh of the 2nd Temple period.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing about Yom Kippur in Megillat Taanit is in chapter 13, which says we fast that day and the golden calf was stoned for that day.

Answer (score 0):

[Megillat Taanit 4:8](http://www.sefaria.org/Megillat_Taanit.4.1-8?lang=he-en&layout=heLeft&sidebarLang=all) (assuming this is the passage to which you are referring) discusses the literalist approach to Biblical interpretation taken by the Boethusians who rejected the Oral Law:

> "and they removed the garment before the elders of the city" - the words as they are written (i.e. literally, as interpreted by the Boethusians; The Oral tradition, however, is otherwise)

It has little to do with Yom Kippur. Rather, Megillat Taanit 4 seems to be explaining the commemoration of 4 Tammuz of a victory over the Boethusians for which reason there was a ban on eulogizing on that day.